# The argument type 'Icon?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was making a reusuable widget. First did it in function then convert it to a stateless Widget. It works fine in the function but somehow give off an error in the stateless widget. My codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final Icon? icon;
  final String text;
  final double radius;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const MyButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.width,
      this.icon,
      this.text = "",
      this.radius = 0,
      required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (icon != null) {
      return Container(
        width: width,
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: icon,
          label: Text(text),
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
          ))),
          onPressed: onPressed,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        width: width,
        child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(text),
            style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
            ))),
            onPressed: onPressed),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The error is at

```
if (icon != null) {
      return Container(
        width: width,
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: icon,
```

> The argument type 'Icon?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'. Open documentation

I have already specify the part where it's not nullable, so I'm out of idea here. It works perfectly fine when it's declared as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind to try this one

```
  icon: icon!,
```

use `!` change `Icon?` to `Icon`, it should be fixed

Answer (score -2):

The Dart compiler is not very good null-checking final properties, so you just need to add a single line to your beautifully-written piece of code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Add the line below
  final Icon? icon = this.icon;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it didn't work. But @Sam Chan's answer has solved it for me. Thank you anyway though for the fast answer.

Comment: It didn't work because you failed. No remorse though.